# How to append objects to a slice?

Tags: go, slice

I am new to golang and I'd like to aggregaet query results into a `results` slice to be pushed to the browser. Here is the code:

```
type Category struct {
    Id          bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Name        string
    Description string
    Tasks       []Task
}


type Cats struct {
    category Category
} 

func CategoriesCtrl(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
    c := session.DB("taskdb").C("categories")

    iter := c.Find(nil).Iter()
    result := Category{}
    results := []Cats //Here is the problem

    for iter.Next(&result) {
        results = append(results, result)
        fmt.Printf("Category:%s, Description:%s\n", result.Name, result.Description)
        tasks := result.Tasks
        for _, v := range tasks {
            fmt.Printf("Task:%s Due:%v\n", v.Description, v.Due)
        }
    }
    if err = iter.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Fprint(w, results)    
}
```

But instead I get

> type []Cats is not an expression

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

You can say

```
results := make([]Cats, 0)
```

or

```
var results []Cats
```

or

```
results := []Cats{}
```

instead.

Comment: `results := []Cats{}` cause this error: `cannot use results (type []Cats) as type Cats in append`

Comment: `results := make([]Cats)` gives error: `missing len argument to make([]Cats)`

Comment: @Karlom, for your append issue, it sounds like you're trying to append a slice to a slice, if so add `...` to the end like `slice1 = append(slice1, slice2...)`

Comment: @user161778, no, using Python vocabulary,  I'm trying to append an object to a list of objects.

Comment: @Karlom, then use append. You have a typo with `append(results, results)` should be `append(results, result)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `results := make([]Cats, len)` instead, where `len` is the initial length of slice.

`results := []Cats{}` will also work.

If you use `var results []Cats`, its initial value is `nil` so you'd need to initialize it before using `append`.

Comment: This gives: ` missing len argument to make([]Cats)`

Comment: `results := make([]Cats, 0)` yields error: `cannot use results (type []Cats) as type Cats in append`

Comment: `results = append(results, result)`  @Karlom

Comment: `results = append(results, result)` is already there, but the error occures at the `results` declaration, not the append line above.

Comment: be careful with the second argument in `append`, it should be `result` not `results` @Karlom

Comment: Thanks siomon. I corrected the typo. but it did not cause the error.